Excel to Visio UML Sequence Diagram, 10k+ messages
I made some sequence diagrams in Visio and wanted to do so for the entire project. Well, I have 10k+ messages and I can't sit there and do it manually.
I did an internet search for Excel to Visio UML sequence diagram, but didn't get anything useful. Microsoft has tools for org charts and flowcharts, but not sequence diagrams. I tried using those tools to make a diagram, but they come out as flowcharts. Am I missing something simple? I feel like it should be easy for me to define actors and message IDs and then import that into Visio. I am willing to switch programs if that makes it easier.
For example, when one opens Visio and uses the simple UML sequence diagram template, they would see this...
Visio UML Template
From that template it is easy to work backwards into excel and come up with this table
Timeline, Message, Origin, Destination
---0---, message1, Actor, Object1
---1---, message2, Object1, Object2
---2---, selfMessage, Object2, Object2
---3---, return, Object2, Object1
---4---, return, Object1, Actor
I would like to first define the table and then use a tool to automatically create a UML diagram. Is there a tool that can read an excel sheet with that information and automatically populate a UML sequence diagram?
Thanks!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hi and welcome to Superuser. You could improve your question by showing us exactly what you have tried to achieve the task in front of you and explaining how your attempted solution failed to achieve the desired goal.

Thank you for your quick response. I have edited my message.
